# Did the HP of Dragonite get nerfed?

Tags: pokemon-go

I just powered-up my first Dragonite to 2750-CP. The IV is 82%. The appraisal says his best attribute is HP. But his new HP is only **135**. My 2750-CP Gyarados has 150-HP. And a 2000-CP Arcanine has 135-HP.

Is a 135-HP a reasonable value for 2750-CP Dragonite?
Why are they called "tanky"?

Before power-up: 1983-CP / 116-HP
After power-up: 2750-CP / 135-HP

The appraisal did say his best attribute was HP...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*The question body doesn't really fit the title, so I'm going to answer both separately.*

### Title: Did the HP of Dragonite get nerfed?

During the major CP rebalance in November 2016, Dragonite's HP actually stayed **exactly the same**, while its Attack was buffed and Defense slightly nerfed. Since then, there have not been any changes to any Pokemon's stats, except for Lapras, which was excluded in November 2016 and retroactively nerfed in February 2017 to match the stat calculation formula every other Pokemon has been using since November 2016.

### Body: Is this a reasonable value for Dragonite? Why are they called "tanky"?

Dragonite has medium HP, there are several Pokemon that have more. Comparing Pokemon via CP is not very useful, though, since their stats can vary greatly. Dragonite has higher Attack and Defense than, say, Arcanine, which is why your Arcanine with the same HP has lower CP. The best way to compare Pokemon is by their level, which is the position of the little dot on the arc above the Pokemon's sprite. If it's all the way on the right, the level is your Trainer level +1.5, so if 2 Pokemon are both maxed out and have the same CP, their total base stats and IVs are roughly the same.

As for why Dragonite is called tanky, this is mainly due to 2 aspects. First, its **Defense** is rather high, especially in comparison to other Pokemon. This reduces the damage it takes, making it live longer even though its HP is relatively low. Second, its **typing** gives it several advantages over commonly used and strong attackers. Dragonite is weak only to Fairy, Dragon, Rock and Ice, all of which are hard to come by on very high CP Pokemon (Ice being the only one that's realistically available on high CP attackers at all). It resists Fire, Grass and Water, among others, which are some of the most common types of high CP attackers' moves. With the prevalence of Water-types in gyms, Grass and Electric are preferred choices for attackers, and a Dragonite thrown into the mix will only take neutral damage from Electric, while it doubly resists Grass, making it hard to efficiently take down a Dragonite in a Water-dominated gym. Gyarados, for comparison, takes neutral damage from Grass and is doubly weak to Electric, so even though its HP is a little higher than Dragonite's (which is also offset by its slightly lower Defense), its typing makes it much easier to take down with the attackers people are using anyway.

Comment: Two Pokemon at the same level with the same HP are bound only to have the same Stamina stat, not any other stats or IVs. If you want to open this up into CP and stat math you should link to another question that goes into it more deeply because the cursory explanation isn't very clear.

Comment: @Eikre Thanks, that was a typo, should say same CP.

Comment: To answer the question in the title, no, Dragonite's base stats remained the same.

Comment: @Jerry actually, since no time frame is given, that's not accurate. They did change in November, although HP was unaffected by this change.

Comment: @scenia, you are right, I was assuming the time frame of the question.  Perhaps you could include this time frame as well into your answer.

Comment: It is in the first sentence (which is the part that refers to the title). Can I somehow make it clearer or more obvious to easily understand? Feel free to edit if you have an idea :)

Comment: The time frame of the question? Feb 19, 2017? The question starts with "I just powered-up ..."  Your answer discusses Nov, 2016.

Comment: @Jerry let me clarify. The question asks "Did the HP of Dragonite get nerfed" without any reference to *when* it might have been nerfed. Since there was exactly one well-known instance of large-scale nerfs and buffs to Pokemon's stats (the one in Nov. 2016), I'm interpreting the title as "Was Dragonite's HP nerfed during that large nerf event or any subsequent, lesser-known balance change?" and since there was no subsequent change, the answer is "it wasn't nerfed in Nov. 2016". I've added a reference to "since then" to make that clearer.